# Firebase security rules bans everyone instead of users in the banned collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am building a chat app in react js using firebase , everything was fine till I tried to implement the banning system. I configured the firebase security rules but It did not really went as expected. The auth rules are working but when it comes to ban the users from the banned collection , it doesnt work , it doesnt give read or write permission to anyone even if it is a non-banned user here are the rules:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid && !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/banned/$(request.auth.uid));
    }
  }
}
```

I expected to ban all the users that are in the banned firestore collection

Comment: `request.resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid` would always fail for a read operation as `request.resource` is defined only in write requests. What are you trying to do? Can you share your code that queries/updates data but is not working ?

Comment: what I am trying to do is , if the user uses bad words then store his uid and displayName in the banned collection instead of the messages and then ban him without the ability to write or read. The code for that is this: ```  const filter = new Filter();  let text = value
    if(filter.isProfane(text)) {
      text = `I got banned for saying ${filter.clean(text)}`
      await addDoc(collection(db , 'banned') , {
        uid,
        user: displayName
      })
      setTimeout(() => {
        signOut(auth)
        navigate('/')
      }, 5000)
      
    } ```